# The view content doesn't refresh when using RedirectToAction method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, redirecttoaction

I create a simple asp.net core mvc project.

The HomeController.cs looks like the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public IActionResult Index(string name, string desc)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        TestViewModel viewModel = new TestViewModel();
        viewModel.Id = random.Next(0,7).ToString();
        viewModel.Name = name;
        viewModel.desc = desc;
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    public IActionResult Update()
    {
        //return View("Index", new TestViewModel() { Name="Steven", desc="Hello" });
        return RedirectToAction("Index", new { name = "Steven", desc="Hello" });
    }
}
```

The ViewModel class:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
}
```

The Razor page:

```html
<!--
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@model WebApplication6.Controllers.TestViewModel

<div class="main">
    <form method="get">
        <label name="id" asp-for="Id">@Model.Id</label>
        <label asp-for="Name">@Model.Name</label>
        <input name="desc" type="text" value="@Model.desc" />
        <input name="t1" type="button" onclick="executeInsert()"/>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeInsert() {
        $.get('/Home/Update');
    }
</script> -->
```

When I click the button, I actually has send the get request and the it has redirected to index action, but the browser doesn't refresh the view content.

Comment: You are calling the action method update in ajax. ajax will not refresh the page or redirect even if the server is doing RedirectToAction. You might want to do actually submit the form using submit button

Comment: Would you kindly have a try and let me know if that works perfectly for you. Let me know if you require any further assistance on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function cannot be invoked this way`$.get('/Home/Update');`
What you are trying to achieve can be done this way more eligantly you could try this sample:

***Controller Loading View:***

```
 public IActionResult Index(string name, string desc)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            TestViewModel viewModel = new TestViewModel();
            viewModel.Id = random.Next(0, 7).ToString();
            viewModel.Name = name;
            viewModel.desc = desc;
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

***Controller Submit New Value:***

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Update(TestViewModel model)
        {
          return RedirectToAction("Index", new { name = model.Name, desc = model.desc });
        }
```

***View:***

```
@model MVCApps.Models.TestViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ViewContentTestIndex";
}

<h3>View Content Test Index</h3>
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "UserLog"))
{

    <div>
        Id: <label name="id" asp-for="Id">@Model.Id</label>
        Name:<label asp-for="Name">@Model.Name</label>
        Desc:<label asp-for="desc">@Model.desc</label>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div>

        <label asp-for="Name">Name</label>
        <input name="Name" type="text" value="@Model.Name" />
        <label asp-for="Name">Desc</label>
        <input name="desc" type="text" value="@Model.desc" />
        <input id="Button" type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>

   
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

I hope it would help you.